# How to make a password UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to set up a UserForm to type a password into. After the password has been entered, I want four buttons to appear on the Worksheet.

The UserForm is called "UserForm2" the TextBox is called "PASSWORD" and the button to enter it is called "OK".

I would like the password to be "admin" (placeholder).

I have a CommandButton called "CommandButton1" on the main sheet that opens the UserForm with this code:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

UserForm2.Show

End Sub
```

Now that I have the UserForm open how do I achieve my goal?

The four buttons I want to appear are standard Excel buttons with macros attached. Will the standard Excel buttons work or will I have to change to CommandButtons to hide and show them?

Also, I am struggling to get the password to be entered and then read.

I found this code online:

```vb
Sub LOGIN()

    Dim PASSWORD As String
    PASSWORD = "ADMIN"
    
    'Check if the password is correct
    If UserForm2.PASSWORD.Value <> PASSWORD Then
        'Display a message and exit the sub-routine if the password is not correct
        MsgBox "Sorry, incorrect password. Please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Incorrect Password"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'The following code will only be executed if the password is correct...
    
    'Close the password input user form now that we don't need it
    Unload UserForm2  

End Sub
```

I am unsure how this is working and how to get it to work for me.

To summarize, I want to click a button to open the UserForm and then type in the password, then click the ok button on the UserForm and then have the four buttons appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 4 (ActiveX command-)buttons I set to `.Visible = False` prior to testing.
Then another button with your code to show the UserForm.

When you right-click your OK button in design-modus, you can choose to go into the code which will look something like (with the code you need):

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
    Dim pwd As String, ws As Worksheet
    pwd = "ADMIN"
    
    'Check if the password is correct
    If Me.PASSWORD.Value <> pwd Then 'adjusted Userform2->Me according to FunThomas' comment
        'Display a message and exit the sub-routine if the password is not correct
        MsgBox "Sorry, incorrect password. Please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Incorrect Password"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'The following code will only be executed if the password is correct...
    
    'Close the password input user form now that we don't need it
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheet")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 5 'my extra "invisible" buttons were called btn2, etc.
        ws.Shapes.Item("btn" & i).Visible = True
    Next i
    
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

That should make them visible if the user types in "ADMIN", "admin" won't work here unless you don't care about capitalizing letters in a password, then just use `UCase(UserForm2.PASSWORD.Value)`

Hope this is clear :)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, ill test this and let you know how I get on with it but this seems very clear to understand! thanks again

Comment: Note that your code is depending on that the user used the default instance of the form. In the code behind of a form, use `Me.` (=object) rather than the form name (=class), else it will fail when user follows the VBA best practice to create a form object. Also, in nearly all cases it is not needed to `Unload` a form, especially not when the code of it is still running. Use `Me.Hide` instead.

Comment: If the password was the only reason for the form, it won't be necessary to have any more code still running, right? I adjusted the Userform -> Me mention.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag you @FunThomas , see my question above about unloading vs hiding ^^

Comment: @Notus_Panda: I don't think it's a good idea that an object destroys itself. Consider that in a next version, the form is also used to identify the user and the calling code wants to read the account name. When the form destroys itself, the calling function will either get a runtime error (as the object is no longer valid) or, when using the default instance, it will read properties of an instance that was freshly created (and therefore the username is likely empty). I don't see any point in `Unload`, but a lot of potential issues.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity, I'll keep it in mind for next time and adjust my answer.